# NetworkSecurityConfig Android Studio Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, internet-connection

Android Studio 2.3.3 give me **NetworkSecurityConfig** and I'm trying 2 days with this problem

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dxnnx.com.soytec">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the call

```
String link = "http://www.google.com";
URL urel = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urel.openConnection();
conn.connect();
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: What's your compileSdkVersion?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53984750/7045328