# NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default Error response code: 400

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, networking

I'm trying to connect to either of these places and get the JSON data:-

```
https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=debate&tag=politics/politics&from-date=2014-01-01&api-key=test
https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=debates&api-key=test
https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
```

All three I can get to via the browser, but when I try to access them via an android app I get the following errors:-

```
NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
Error response code: 400
```

I've added this to manifest.xml:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I also added this to the manifest.xml:-

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

And created res/xml/network_security_config.xml, which contains:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">content.guardianapis.com</domain>>
    </domain-config>
```

Which changes the error to:-

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
Error response code: 400
```

I know it's missing:-

```
<trust-anchors>
    <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
</trust-anchors>
```

but I have no idea where or what the certificate would be or if it's needed.

Not really sure what is going on, any help would be appreciated.

IN ADDITION:-
I am able to connect fine and get the JSON from this URL:-

```
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time&minmag=6&limit=10
```

All I get is this:-

```
No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

Buy not error 400 and gets through with a 200 instead. So it makes me think there is something weird going on, but not sure where.

Comment: Unless you want to restrict the urls your app can hit for some reason, you don't really need to make a custom network security config-  the default is almost always sufficient.  The only time it isn't is if you have an untrusted cert for your service, which is basically never these days with Let's Encrypt being almost free.

Comment: Add this in application tag:-

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: Thanks, I did start without it, I just added the network security in an effort to try and get it to work.

Comment: Please share the device os , modal and also api usage ie code where you are calling the api method , Thanks

Comment: Changed to usesCleartextTraffic="true", still gives same code 400 error.

Comment: Do study on this - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try these solutions

> **Solution 1**)

Add the following attribute to the `<application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

> **Solution 2**)

Add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to the `<application` tag in `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

With a corresponding `network_security_config.xml` in `app/src/main/res/xml/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

[image]

Refer this answer for more info:
[Download Manger not working in Android Pie 9.0 (Xiaomi mi A2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493077/files-are-not-downloading-on-android-pie-9-0-xiaomi-mi-a2-using-download-mange)

Comment: Sorry still no luck. I'm wondering if it may be an issue with how I'm making the request to the server. It is a simple GET request, so I'm not sure why that could be. I'll look into it further.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what are each of these solutions mean?

Comment: Man, for someone who specializes in iOS development, what is up with the need for that long path location? You saved me with that detail which was missing from the Android guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

**Edited Answer**
Remove  `<domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>` from the code.

Use just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

### And It will work for any URL or IP.

Try to set `cleartextTrafficPermitted=false`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still getting:- Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true, Error response code: 400

Comment: @Markus how did you solve it? I am also getting the same issue in one of my projects. There is something related to the server. As I have solved this using same solution for a different project. Do let me know.

Comment: The issues ended up being an error in my URL string requesting the information, which caused the Error 400. Once I corrected my URL API request string it worked fine.

Comment: But, My Url was correct, and I banged my head but cannot resolve. So, I tried the code I am adding as an answer. It works for any url or IP.

Comment: I meant the error was in the URL request, the site could not understand the request, so it returned an error 400.

Comment: About the URL , it was set to `cleartextTrafficPermitted="false"` . I've edited the answer. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

i was also facing the same problem ,and tried many solutions(adding config etc things),but they didn't work for me..I sit and checked my code carefully, There was something wrong in the code which i've wrote to access the node. Not  a syntactic error, it's node name missmatch.

Answer (score 1):

Open `AndroidManifest.xml` file at **app/src/main** folder, add this line of code inside application tag

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

And now, you have to create a file named **network_security_config.xml** at this location app/src/main/res/xml, add following code into this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

If you have already do this, then just make sure that you have above code in your file. If your file contains domain named remove that line

```
Remove <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.etc.com</domain> from the code.
```

And I have also done one more thing, I have removed this line of code from my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

which will be in your activity tag.