# java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to t.main.wedeep.com.cn not permitted by network security policy

Tags: android, okhttp, android-9.0-pie, download-manager

I got above error when i use mockhttpserver to test http request, the following code is how i create service.

```
   fun <T> getService(clazz: Class<T>): T {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor()).addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE })
                .build()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url(""))
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GSON))
                .build()
                .create(clazz)
    }
```

This is my Test code.

```
@UninstallModules(HomePageDataModule::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class TestHomePageViewModel {


    private lateinit var viewModel: HomePageViewModel

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Inject
    lateinit var cpd: CompositionDao

    @Inject
    lateinit var csd: CompositionsDao

    @Inject
    lateinit var hpds: HomePageDataSource

    @Inject
    lateinit var ss :HomePageService

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        viewModel = HomePageViewModel(HomeCompositionsRepository(cpd, csd, hpds, Util.GSON))

    }





    @Test
    fun testObserveHomeData() {

        val data = Util.getFileString("mainpage.json")
        val rr  = GSON.fromJson(data,Array<HomePreviewView>::class.java)
        println(rr)
        enqueueResponse("mainpage.json")
        runBlocking {
            val result = ss.getHomeData()
            Assert.assertNotEquals(rr.size,result.body()!!.size)
        }
}
```

**Everything works smoothly on my app except running my unit test code.**
There is a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) , but my issue has a little difference compare to that one.
Plenty of ways from that similar question i have tried, but not work.

PS: If the test code run on Junit4Test but not AndroidJunit4Test, it works properly. But now i need to exectue a integrate test. So this part of code need to be executed on AndroidJunit4Test

Comment: Make sure your host is secure for your application or you can just add this line of code inside your manifest file. 

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: @AslamHossin I have no idea why it does not work for me when i execute above unit test code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984725/networksecurityconfig-no-network-security-config-specified-using-platform-defa/53984915#53984915

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: @Cyrus 
When the attribute is set to "false", platform components (for example, HTTP and FTP stacks, DownloadManager, and MediaPlayer) will refuse the app's requests to use cleartext traffic. Third-party libraries are strongly encouraged to honor this setting as well. The key reason for avoiding cleartext traffic is the lack of confidentiality, authenticity, and protections against tampering; a network attacker can eavesdrop on transmitted data and also modify it without being detected.
More
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic

Comment: You can also use mockWebServer.useTls and client.insecureHost to use SSL for the test connections.

Answer (score 23):

**Solution 1)**

Add the following attribute to the `<application` tag in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

**Solution 2)**

Add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to the `<application` tag in `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

With a corresponding `network_security_config.xml` in `app/src/main/res/xml/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Post the error , also shared other details like device , sdk etc

Comment: I don't know why but just solution2 worked for me in api 30

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I added this to the android manifest file:

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`