# Override resource files in Android instrumented tests

Tags: android, instrumented-test

*Disclaimer: related but different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77356085/instrumented-test-uses-main-androidmanifest-instead-of-the-test-version), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27884436/1368342) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032000/java-net-unknownserviceexception-cleartext-communication-to-t-main-wedeep-com-c).*

I would like to point `AndroidManifest.xml` to an xml resource file like this:

```xml
    <application
        [...]
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

Where the "normal" build gets it from *app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml* (note the **main**) and the instrumented test build gets it from *app/src/androidTest/res/xml/network_security_config.xml* (note the **androidTest**).

Note that the xml file looks like this in this case, but I think it's irrelevant:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>
```

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work: the resource in "androidTest/" is just ignored. However, I can override the file in debug builds by putting it into *app/src/debug/res/xml/network_security_config.xml*. While that "does the job", it's not exactly what I want: it overrides the file for debug builds, and I want to override the file for the instrumented tests.

Is there any way I could tell Android to use my "androidTest/" resources when building instrumented tests?