# NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource "network_security_config" debugBuild: true

Tags: android, kotlin

Tell me how you can fix it?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    <activity>
       ...
    </activity>
</application>
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<network_security_config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
</network_security_config>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984725/networksecurityconfig-no-network-security-config-specified-using-platform-defa/53984915#53984915

Comment: "Tell me how you can fix it?" -- there is nothing to fix. This is a log message. It is not a crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare the application is immediately closed when this error is exited

Comment: Then you should be looking for [a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/115145). This is an ordinary message and does not indicate a problem, let alone one that would cause an app process to be terminated.

Comment: post strack trace here also

Comment: I found my mistake, it was not related to the manifest settings. Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you fix this issue yet? @j.ss

Comment: @K.Sopheak: This question is poorly written, so it is unclear what you are expecting for an answer. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] and explain, in detail, what your problem is and what your symptoms are.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
     <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score -2):

if you are using this `android:networkSecurityConfig` then remove    `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

**For reference**
[NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984725/networksecurityconfig-no-network-security-config-specified-using-platform-defa/53984915#53984915)

Comment: 1) uninstall app and try again , 
2) restart your device and try again

Comment: 3. Update google play service in your device and restart app

Comment: 1) app was deleted
2) i use AVD Pixel 2 API 28, 29. Google play is last version

Comment: can you please test it on real device