# is there a way to play http hls media resource in exoplayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

i am trying to play a hls uri with exoplayer in java

whem i give a uri with https protocol it plays well but in case of http protocol the content is not ben played

but when i play the same links with other players like mxplayer or vlc media player it is played well

can anypne help

`ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

```
    binding.playerView.setPlayer(player);

    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri("http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/1878761/sp/187876100/playManifest/entryId/1_usagz19w/flavorIds/1_5spqkazq,1_nslowvhp,1_boih5aji,1_qahc37ag/format/applehttp/protocol/http/a.m3u8");
    player.addMediaItem(mediaItem);

    player.prepare();

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);`
```

Answer (score 0):

XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Widget for exoplayer view-->
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/exoPlayerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Class file-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var playerView: StyledPlayerView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
      playerView = findViewById(R.id.exoPlayerView)
        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
        val hlsMediaSource: HlsMediaSource = HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/1878761/sp/187876100/playManifest/entryId/1_usagz19w/flavorIds/1_5spqkazq,1_nslowvhp,1_boih5aji,1_qahc37ag/format/applehttp/protocol/http/a.m3u8"))
        val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        player.setMediaSource(hlsMediaSource)
        playerView?.player = player
        player.prepare()
        player.playWhenReady = true
    }
}
```

Manifest File-

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and [add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53984915/18362930) this code

Comment: This is not working have to tried to play the link using the code with you have given

Comment: @MilansinghChouhan I have checked and it working for me updated the code

Answer (score 0):

By default, ExoPlayer will not play HTTP content now - many players and browser now impose this restriction as their standard behaviour.

From the current , at the the time of writing ExoPlayer documentation (https://exoplayer.dev/troubleshooting.html):

> Fixing “Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted” errors
>
> This error will occur if your app requests cleartext HTTP traffic (i.e., http:// rather than https://) when its Network Security Configuration does not permit it. If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or later, cleartext HTTP traffic is disabled by the default configuration.
>
> If your app needs to work with cleartext HTTP traffic then you need to use a Network Security Configuration that permits it. Please see Android’s network security documentation for details. To enable all cleartext HTTP traffic, you can simply add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the application element of your app’s AndroidManifest.xml.
>
> The ExoPlayer demo app uses the default Network Security Configuration, and so does not allow cleartext HTTP traffic. You can enable it using the instructions above.

As a first step you can try as they suggest and add 'android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"' to your manifest.