# Android App does not connect to server on Vi mobile internet

Tags: android, networking, retrofit

APIs works fine when I use Wi-fi or any other network provider, but when I try to run APIs on Vi internet (Indian sim), It returns unknown host UnknownHostException.

- I am using **Retrofit**.
- I tried adding **network-security-config** too but that did not help. ([NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default Error response code: 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984725/networksecurityconfig-no-network-security-config-specified-using-platform-defa))
- `cleartextTrafficPermitted = true`

On the other apps, internet works fine.